# PHP mail sometimes sends subject only (empty body)

Tags: php, html, email

So the problem is that sometimes, while using the PHP mail form on my web site, it only sends the subject line and an empty body! But this only happens SOMETIMES. rarely actually. I was getting emails from web site users (with subject line, but blank body), so I assumed they just submitted form too early, until I tested a handful of emails myself, and i ended up with some blanks myself! Again, subject line is always there though.

Form CODE here:

```
echo "<form method='POST' action='item.php?id=$strItemNumber'>
<table><tr><td style='vertical-align:middle;'>
Subject:<BR />
<input type='text' name='subject' value='Item # $strItemNumber'  size='19'><br />
Name:<BR /> <input type='text' name='name' size='19'>
<br />Your Email:<br />
<input type='text' name='email' size='19'>

</td><td>
Message:<BR />
<textarea rows='9' name='message' cols='60'></textarea>

</tr></table>
<input type='submit' value='Send Email' name='submitted'>
</form>";
```

code for email function here:

```
$to = "info@mydomain.com";
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$name_field = $_POST['name'];
$email_field = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$body = "From: $name_field\n E-Mail: $email_field\n Message:\n $message\n"; 

mail($to, $subject, $body);
```

Do you guys have any thoughts?

Thank you

Comment: it sounds entirely like a code problem. please provide.

Comment: No offense, but Yahoo web hosting is much less likely to be at fault than your one-off code.

Comment: okay guys code is here - ithcy, no offense taken - it was just my theory. Didn't wanna do the work to pull up coding if it was not thought necessary to see. but anyhow, here it is...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `$body` to the following:

```
$body = "From: {$name_field} E-Mail: {$email_field} Message: {$message}";
```

Comment: MOOSEMAN, trying this gives me blank emails. all of them are blank when I change to this... hmm

Comment: but i think you are definitely on track with something. the variable $body must be not getting set to anything. let me change the way the string is built and see if it works....

Comment: okay so i changed the way the string was built. it is now: 

$body = "From: " . $name_field . "\n E-Mail: " . $email_field . "\n Message: " . $message; 

I guess I'll wait and see within a day or two, if it has not been resolved, I will see a blank email from my tests, or users on the site and I will know the outcome.

Comment: Hope this helps. Using `{$variable}` inside a string inside double quotes should be identical to your `".$variable."`. Perhaps your host uses an old version of PHP. ( < 5.2)

Comment: okay, bad news... received more blank emails :( - not sure what is going on.

Comment: Try logging the value of `$message` somewhere. See if that's ever blank.

Comment: I had that in mind, but how can I log that? it's so weird because it happens only once in a while. I guess I can try to make a test page for me alone and try to echo out the $body variable. would take some while of testing since it happens at random I guess.

Comment: Found a line in one of the website logs. access.log file has a line that says: "GET /mailer.php?email=1&message=1&name=1&subject=1&submit=Submit

not sure if this has anything to do with any of this stuff.

Comment: You could check if `$message` is empty before the email is sent. Something like `if(!isset($message) || ($message === ""){ "mail("your_address@example.com", "Empty message variable", date('c')); };` should do it.

Comment: I implemented something like this... also, i took out the back slashes to see if that may help.... I should also mention that earlier today, two emails came in from two different pages on our website, those two came in almost at the same time from 2 diff users - and BOTH were blank! so basically, it's almost as if the emails mess up when server might have a certain stressload or something... which brings me again, back to questioning the web host or server being at fault.

Comment: by the way, for anyone who ever comes across this page - since my email body was coming in blank, and the body included users email that they filled out on the form, i just added email to the subject line. let's hope that subject line email gets included in blank emails now. that way i can reply to the sender and ask what their original message was to begin with. - this will also let me see if somehow the user email variable is blank as well. then I will know that ALL these variables are not getting set in the POST method or something. at least I will be one step closer to finding the issue

Comment: Where is `$message` filled in from? A database or post variable?

Comment: there is the form which user fills out, then a post action happens. then as you see, $_POST['message'] on the .php page receives the inputted text.

Comment: Do you have any kind of validation on the form?

Comment: no validation. you mean like checking if the inputted email is an includes an @ and a . after the @ ? or if message is actually empty, do not send it but display error? I should implement the latter(empty message field validation) - now that I think about it.

Comment: Form validation is just checking that fields are filled out satisfactorily, and displaying an error if they are not. Checking that an email address is valid or every field is filled in are just two types of validation. It's best practice to have PHP *and* JavaScript validation for a form, but the JavaScript validation can be avoided.

Comment: So my host is now changed and I don't have this issue anymore. I guess it was a host issue. Never use Yahoo!!! So glad I'm out of there.

Answer (score 0):

Ok.  This answer is to the original poster.  I had the same exact issue for a few hours.  I was beating my head on the wall, when i discovered a little tidbit that caught my attention from the PHP wiki.  Turns out that the body must be composed of lines.  Each line must end with the infamous **'\n\r'**.  This may or may not manifest in the email, but is critical to the email body string.  Each line cannot exceed a particular length.  In Yahoos case, i do not know the exact length, but the wiki states 70 character length.  I think it is not exact. Since my data i was emailing was html code, i simply inserted the **'\n\r'** to the end of every html tag.  I have not had the issue anymore. I suspect the message body you were sending occasionally exceeded the data limit to the line length and just sent blank a message body.

Example String:

```
"<body>Hello World</body>\n\r<i>Something, something, darkside</i>\n\r..."
```

At least for me, this solved the issue and i am also on Yahoo!

I realize this post is an ancient artifact, by internet standards, but i see lots-O-views associated, and i'm sure someone will find it handy.